# Relation on positive real numbers: $x\mathrel{R}y$ if and only if $x\le y^2$ is transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is a relation defined on the set of positive real numbers as: “$x\mathrel{R}y$ if and only if $x\le y^2$”, how to prove that $R$ is transitive?

Comment: $x\leq y$ or $x\leq y^2$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Do you know the definition of transitivity? If not, can you look for it. If yes, what have you tried?

Comment: If x and y are both less than or equal to 1 then it is obvious that x<=y^2,y<=z^2 imply x<=z^2. But if x,y,z are all greater than or equal to 1 then how to prove that x<=y^2, y<=z^2 imply x<=z^2?

Comment: $2\leq \sqrt{2}^2$ and $\sqrt{2}\leq {\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}^2$, but $2>\sqrt{2}=(\sqrt{\sqrt{2}})^2$.

Comment: Is it transitive for positive integers?

Comment: Put the example I gave you into the definition.

Comment: Thanks treeleat